# Can I use Win32 COM to replace text inside a word document?

Tags: python, winapi, com, ms-word, replace

I have to perform a large number of replacements in some documents, and the thing is, I would like to be able to automate that task. Some of the documents contain common strings, and this would be pretty useful if it could be automated. From what I read so far, COM could be one way of doing this, but I don't know if text replacement is supported.
I'd like to be able to perform this task in python? Is it possible? Could you post a code snippet showing how to access the document's text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if [this](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Windows-Programming-in-Python/2/) gives you a start on word automation using python.

Once you open a document, you could do the following.
After the following code, you can Close the document & open another.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "test"
    .Replacement.Text = "test2"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

The above code replaces the text "test" with "test2" and does a "replace all".
You can turn other options true/false depending on what you need.

The simple way to learn this is to create a macro with actions you want to take, see the generated code & use it in your own example (with/without modified parameters).

EDIT: After looking at some code by Matthew, you could do the following

```
MSWord.Documents.Open(filename)
Selection = MSWord.Selection
```

And then translate the above VB code to Python.
Note: The following VB code is shorthand way of assigning property without using the long syntax.

(VB)

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "test"
    .Replacement.Text = "test2"
End With
```

Python

```
find = Selection.Find
find.Text = "test"
find.Replacement.Text = "test2"
```

Pardon my python knowledge. But, I hope you get the idea to move forward.
Remember to do a Save & Close on Document, after you are done with the find/replace operation.

In the end, you could call `MSWord.Quit` (to release Word object from memory).

Comment: Bernie's answer includes actual complete python code. This answer could be more terse, and include more complete python.

Comment: How to Highlight text in word document using win32?

Answer (score 13):

I like the answers so far; 
here's a tested example (slightly modified from [here](http://www.programmingforums.org/post105986.html)) 
that replaces all occurrences of a string in a Word document:

```
import win32com.client

def search_replace_all(word_file, find_str, replace_str):
    ''' replace all occurrences of `find_str` w/ `replace_str` in `word_file` '''
    wdFindContinue = 1
    wdReplaceAll = 2

    # Dispatch() attempts to do a GetObject() before creating a new one.
    # DispatchEx() just creates a new one. 
    app = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
    app.Visible = 0
    app.DisplayAlerts = 0
    app.Documents.Open(word_file)

    # expression.Execute(FindText, MatchCase, MatchWholeWord,
    #   MatchWildcards, MatchSoundsLike, MatchAllWordForms, Forward, 
    #   Wrap, Format, ReplaceWith, Replace)
    app.Selection.Find.Execute(find_str, False, False, False, False, False, \
        True, wdFindContinue, False, replace_str, wdReplaceAll)
    app.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges=True)
    app.Quit()

f = 'c:/path/to/my/word.doc'
search_replace_all(f, 'string_to_be_replaced', 'replacement_str')
```

Comment: I like that this has a complete example.

Comment: How to Highlight text in word document using win32?

Answer (score 3):

If [this mailing list post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-April/259213.html) is right, accessing the document's text is a simple as:

```
MSWord = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
MSWord.Visible = 0 
MSWord.Documents.Open(filename)
docText = MSWord.Documents[0].Content
```

Also see [How to: Search for and Replace Text in Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f65x8z3d.aspx).  The examples use VB and C#, but the basics should apply to Python too.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this link: http://python.net/crew/pirx/spam7/

The links on the left side point to the documentation.

You can generalize this using the object model, which is found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this using **VBScript**. Just type the code into a file named `script.vbs`, then open a command prompt (Start -> Run -> Cmd), then switch to the folder where the script is and type:

```
cscript script.vbs
```

```
strFolder = "C:\Files"

Const wdFormatDocument  = 0

'Select all files in strFolder
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='" & strFolder & "'} Where " _
        & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile")

'Start MS Word
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Const wdReplaceAll = 2
Const wdOrientLandscape = 1


For Each objFile in colFiles
    If objFile.Extension = "doc" Then
        strFile = strFolder & "\" & objFile.FileName & "." & objFile.Extension
        strNewFile = strFolder & "\" & objFile.FileName & ".doc"
        Wscript.Echo "Processing " & objFile.Name & "..."

        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strFile)

        objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape

        'Replace text - ^p in a string stands for new paragraph; ^m stands for page break
        Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
        objSelection.Find.Text = "String to replace"
        objSelection.Find.Forward = TRUE
        objSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = "New string"

        objSelection.Find.Execute ,,,,,,,,,,wdReplaceAll

        objDoc.SaveAs strNewFile, wdFormatDocument
        objDoc.Close
        Wscript.Echo "Ready"
    End If
Next

objWord.Quit
```

Comment: OP asked about python in particular.