# Find.Execute not working with package Win32com

Tags: python, replace, ms-word, win32com

I got a document where I want to find a list of words and replace them with other words. Here is my code :

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
word.DisplayAlerts = False
word.Documents.Open(path)

FromTo = {"<#TITLE#>":"The title I want", "<#COMPANY#>":"My Company"}

for From in FromTo.keys():
    word.Selection.Find.Text = From
    word.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = FromTo[From]
    word.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace=2, Forward=True)

word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(path)
```

The thing is that the document is opened, the text to find is selected properly, but nothing happens as the code comes to line `word.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace=2, Forward=True)`. The document is normally saved after that, and I got no error message.

Does someone have an idea about why this code doesn't work? It's quite weird that the same code worked two weeks ago and doesn't make anything right now.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, either. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045628/can-i-use-win32-com-to-replace-text-inside-a-word-document) question - the second answer down by 'bernie'  has code that works (for me) if I replace your `execute` line with the one there (replacing vars as necessary). I'll leave it to you to figure out why :)

Comment: As an aside, it would be more Pythonic to use `for From, To in FromTo.items():`, and replace `FromTo[From]` with `To`. Even more so to use lower-case variable names, but beware that `from` is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I  and found that if I change `gen_py` to `xxgen_py` in site-packages\win32com (essentially making it unusable) I no longer have this issue. I'm not sure what is going on, but this was the only way I could get `fin.execute` to actually replace the words and not just highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
for From in FromTo.keys():
    word.Selection.Find.Text = From
    word.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = FromTo[From]
    word.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace=2, Forward=True)
```

try this:

```
for From in FromTo.keys():
    word.Selection.Find.Execute(From, False, False, False, False, False, True, 0, False, FromTo[From], 2)
```